# Loading indicator inside image whilst image is loading

Tags: jquery, image, loading, indicator

I quite like the effect presented here:

http://rascals.eu/templates/rt0802/portfolios/portfolio-2-columns/

The problem however is that if you look at the source code you'll notice that there aren't any  - it's all done via jquery and links created like this:

```
<a href="xxx.jpg" rel="lightbox[portfolio]" style="width: 446px; height: 205px" class="autoload hover" data-image_url="yyy.jpg"></a>
```

with an image probably created in the background and then inserted in that location at load.

However, is this possible in a different way, more standards compliant way? Can anyone guide me towards any resources/tutorials if so?

Thanks.

Edit: By standards compliant I mean:

With the img src pointing to the correct location so that images still display when js is disabled.

Comment: What do you mean with more standards way? Without jQuery?

Comment: With the <img src pointing to the correct location so that images still display when js is disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do

```
img {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(...);
  background-position: center center;
}
```

If the background image you use is cached it should appear before the images do. (Watch out for transparent images, since they will have the background behind them.)

Comment: I'm so tempted to edit your answer to use the `background` shorthand :D

Comment: @thirtydot Ha! If you do, you better do it in the right order :) Fine, if you must, you have my permission to add a second code block with the shorthand version, (include a black background color). :)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the Ariel's way will help. However, the very first load of the website, you won't be able to see the loading image though as some browsers are loading backgrounds after starting loading the images (img tag). Next time, image will be cached and the page will look good. And as was already mentioned this way is good for images which are not transparent.
I usually use this background technique with loading image myself :)

Comment: Only problem is the way firefox displays it, they show the alt tag (this can be set to color:white though) and also some small image in the upper left corner whilst the image is loading.